# Can I convert a DateTimeField to a string for use with my model with wicket

Tags: jodatime, wicket-1.6

So I have DateTimeField (a TimeField really... But wicket is obscure enough).  It would seem to instantiate this field the PropertyModel needs to be of Type.  Well, In my model, I have the date as a type of string.  That is how it will be stored in the database.  There are other downstream consequences as well.  Is there a way in wicket to convert the type of the Timefield to string instead of date?

right now I am overriding toString().  I doubt that will do anything, but hey, its worth a shot.

Sample code for those who need it to answer abstract questions (the model is the SimpleObjectVO btw):

```
public SimpleObjectVO
{
    ...
    String wackyDueTime = null;
}

...

wackyDueTime = new TimeField("wackyDueTime", new PropertyModel<Date>(model, , "wackyDueTime"))
{
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return HOURS + ":" + MINUTES + " " + AM_OR_PM_CHOICE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TimeField works with `java.util.Date()`. You can use Date for the UI and then store it as you'd like in the database.

Comment: My Vo uses a string.  I guess I would have to have convert from Date to String in that layer.  We have a repo layer where that happens.

Comment: Yes, the View Object should simplify the view.